# How to set a SMS sender to be a Known sender in Messages

Tags: ios, messages, contacts, sms

How do you set a sender of an SMS message to be a known sender.

If it is a plain phone number you can hit the info button and add to contacts sometimes. But this does not work always - I have senders e.g. my bank and my doctor that do not show a phone number just a code. I ask this now as iPhone Messages now puts up a note do I want to Report Junk which it defintely is not.

My bank is also in my contacts and shows in known contacts but message says it is not in my contact list and shows me the Report Junk link.

Also I have known senders that are not in my contacts - I think just by replying. So Known/Unknown senders appears to be rather random.

Answer (score 0):

Send a reply to the message and it will be considered known.

But if you want the conversation to show the name of the sender, you should add it to Contacts. You can do this by clicking on the sender, then clicking on "Info", then either "Create New Contact" or "Add to Existing Contact".